# Outlook - VBA set signature to new Email ... so the signature can be changed via menu

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a script where I add a signature from an htm file in the appData ... signature folder to a newly opened email.

My question is - how do i modify this VBA script to add that signature in a way so Outlook knows its a signature and the signature might be changed by a user via gui.

I assume it may have something to do with setting a "_MailAutoSig" bookmark, is that right?

Script looks like this and works so far:

```
    Dim WithEvents m_objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim LODGIT_SUBJECT_IDENTIFIERS() As String

    Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
        'MsgBox "Application_ItemLoad"
        Select Case Item.Class
            Case olMail
                Set m_objMail = Item
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_objMail_Open(Cancel As Boolean)

        'string array containing lodgit email subject identifiers (beginning string!!! of email subject)
        LODGIT_SUBJECT_IDENTIFIERS = Split("Angebot von Bödele Alpenhotel,Angebot von,bestätigt Ihre Reservierung,Rechnung Nr.,Stornogutschrift für die Rechnung,Ausstehende Zahlung", ",")

        Dim Application As Object
        Dim oOutApp As Object, oOutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String, FixedHtmlBody As String
        Dim Ret

        Set Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
        ' C:\Users\nicole\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
        Ret = Environ("appdata") & _
                    "\Microsoft\Signatures\AH Andrea kurz.htm"

        If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

        '~~> Use the function to fix image paths in the htm file
        FixedHtmlBody = FixHtmlBody(Ret)

        'CHECK FOR LODGIT IDENTIFIER
        If myInStr(m_objMail.Subject, LODGIT_SUBJECT_IDENTIFIERS()) Then
            Debug.Print "E-Mail as from Lodgit identified"
            Dim str As String
            Dim a As Object
            str = Replace(m_objMail.Body, vbCrLf, "<br>")
            str = Replace(str, vbNewLine, "<br>")


            m_objMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:""Times New Roman"" '>" & str & "</span>" & FixedHtmlBody & "</body></html>"

        End If

    End Sub

    '~~> Function to fix image paths in Signature .htm Files
    Function FixHtmlBody(r As Variant) As String
        Dim FullPath As String, filename As String
        Dim FilenameWithoutExtn As String
        Dim foldername As String
        Dim MyData As String

        '~~> Read the html file as text file in a string variable
        Open r For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1

        '~~> Get File Name from path
        filename = GetFilenameFromPath(r)
        '~~> Get File Name without extension
        FilenameWithoutExtn = Left(filename, (InStrRev(filename, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
        '~~> Get the foldername where the images are stored
        foldername = FilenameWithoutExtn & "-Dateien"

        '~~> Full Path of Folder
        FullPath = Left(r, InStrRev(r, "\")) & foldername

        '~~> To cater for spaces in signature file name
        'FullPath = Replace(FullPath, " ", "%20")

        '~~> Replace incomplete path with full Path
        FixHtmlBody = Replace(MyData, "AH%20Andrea%20kurz-Dateien", FullPath)
        'FixHtmlBody = Replace(MyData, foldername, FullPath)
    End Function

    '~~> Gets File Name from path
    Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
        If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then _
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End Function

    'check if str contains on of the elements of a str array
    Public Function myInStr(myString As String, a() As String) As Boolean
        For Each elem In a
            If InStr(1, myString, elem, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                myInStr = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        myInStr = False
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook looks for the "_MailAutoSig" bookmark. This needs to be done with Word Object Model, not by setting the HTMLBody property. Something along the lines:

```
wdStory = 6
wdMove = 0

Set objBkm = Nothing
Set objDoc = Inspector.WordEditor

Set objSel = objDoc.Application.Selection

'remember the cursor position
set cursorRange = objDoc.Range
cursorRange.Start = objSel.Start
cursorRange.End = objSel.End

If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailAutoSig") Then
   'replace old signature
   Debug.Print "old signature found"
   set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
   objBkm.Select
   objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
ElseIf objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailOriginal") Then
  ' is there the original email? (_MailOriginal)
  set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailOriginal")
  objSel.Start = objBkm.Start-2 'give room for the line break before. It includes the line
  objSel.End = objBkm.Start-2
Else
  'insert at the end of the email
  objSel.EndOf wdStory, wdMove
End If

'start bookmark
set bkmStart = objDoc.Bookmarks.Add("_tempStart", objSel.Range)

'end bookmark
set bkmEnd = objDoc.Bookmarks.Add("_tempEnd", objSel.Range)
bkmEnd.End = bkmEnd.End + 1
bkmEnd.Start = bkmEnd.Start + 1
objSel.Text = " "

set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks.Add("_MailAutoSig", bkmStart.Range)

objBkm.Range.insertFile "c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\test.htm", , false, false, false
objBkm.Range.InsertParagraphBefore
objBkm.End = bkmEnd.Start - 1 'since we added 1 above for bkmEnd

objSel.Start = cursorRange.Start
objSel.End = cursorRange.End

bkmStart.Delete
bkmEnd.Delete
```

Comment: I don't really get all the start /end bookmark ... when my email opens (by another programm) its format txt with a preset text ... there will basically never be a signature preset.

When I run your code there is an error on 'start bookmark cause the objSel.Range seems to be empty ... or not set.

What i did manage to make run is:

Comment: Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks.Add("_MailAutoSig")
    objBkm.Range.insertFile "pathToFile", , False, False, False
    objBkm.Range.InsertParagraphBefore

this worked - including that the user could change the sign via gui, however this added the signature to the beginning of the email

Comment: Then insert it at the end. Or add your text to the message body after inserting the signature.

Comment: i see, good idea ... how do you suggest adding the signature to the end of the text?

Comment: The script adds the signature at the bottom of the message body. Do you add your text **before** inserting the signature?

Comment: yes text is already there ... a 3rd party software opens the new outlook email with a preset text. however i manged to make it work now

Comment: seems you script relies on a text passage beeing preselected? Set objSel = objDoc.Application.Selection
??

Comment: No, that was for the current cursor position.